# Convert string to rubbish

Tags: java, string

I am trying to create a function which takes in an input string and returns rubbish string value

```
String foobar (String input)
{
  String rubbish;
  ......
  ......
  returns rubbish

}
```

The rubbish string value is similar to the below

[image]

**I would appreciate it if someone is able to provide me with a sample function or guide me on how to go about doing it**

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? How should the given `String` influence the "rubbish"? Are you trying to generate some kind of hash? For me, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The given string need not influence the rubbish, i am not trying to generate a hash

Comment: So the same string can generate different rubbish values?

Comment: And why then have it as parameter? I think this is an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What is your overall goal with this?

Comment: I think the real question hasn't been asked.And that is how could this be useful to anyone.And if it was useful why do you need our help this is pretty basic stuff you can cast an int to char and generate ints. You have 1252 points ... No the real question is where is your club TROLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function that will return the same garbage for the same input string, this would work fine.

```
public String rubbish(String input)
{
    String result = "";

    long seed = 0;
    long size = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i ++)
    {
        seed += input.charAt(i);
    }

    seed %= Long.MAX_VALUE;
    size = seed % 3000;

    Random rand = new Random(seed);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
    {
        result += (char)rand.nextInt(256);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Additionally, if you want the string to be different each time, you can change `new Random(seed)` to `new Random()` and it'll randomize the string.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a String input?

```
String foo(){return "everythingyouwant";}
```

If you don't need your input and output to be related, that's enough

Comment: That a question and no answer. Therefore it should be a comment.

Comment: @Turing85 Never heard about rhetorical questions?

Comment: Furthermore, he never mentioned *random* values, that's why returning a String literal answers his question

Answer (score 1):

This method will make random "rubbish":

```
String foobar(String input){
    //dont know for what is there input parameter
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int length=(int)(Math.random()*1000); //random length from 0 to 1000
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        sb.append((char)(Math.random()*Character.MAX_VALUE)); //random character
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here a sample to generate a random string using the ascii table

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String res = rubbish();
    System.out.println(res);

}

private static String rubbish() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        sb.append(Character.valueOf((char)randomGenerator.nextInt(231)));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

> «P/?e?}?Ò¤*q5?jf?|c¤(J¨EA?,_#æ®£?ßNÖL?¿¢D??³?Ñ?X©Â»É.~1¡c??¨E ]?p4¬N¶¦¤JVÕ·25??áÇÇbÒ?9?xÓ
>   ?~?!rlÃ?ß0h)È?v?}¸-???´+-?à¼³?ÙÒZ¨I3-Ï¦Ø?/?CÎ??}?©¶gã?©

Answer (score 0):

store the mess in a file 
and do

```
private String mess=""; 

public void loadFile(String absolutePath){
Scanner scanner;
try{scanner=new Scanner(new File(absolutePath));
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){mess+=scanner.nextLine();}
scanner.close();
}catch(Exception){
if(scanner!=null){scanner.close();}
}
}
```

and return mess in your function